# Single TextWatcher for multiple EditTexts?

Tags: android, android-edittext, textwatcher

I have multiple(12) EditTexts in my activity in pairs of 2. I want to do an action for each pair when the text in them changes. Do I need to have 6 different TextWatchers or is there a way to use the same one for or and do some kind of switch?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use Single TextWatcher for multiple EditTexts?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5702771/how-to-use-single-textwatcher-for-multiple-edittexts)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can attach the same [TextWatcher](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/TextWatcher.html) watch to each [EditText](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/EditText.html). Depending on what you need to do you may need to create you implementation of [TextWatcher](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/TextWatcher.html) with some context.

Answer (score 1):

I needed this so i made a reusable one ...i extended off textwatcher class so i could pass in the view i want to watch.

```
/**
 *  
 * A TextWatcher which can be reused
 *  
 */
public class ReusableTextWatcher implements TextWatcher {

    private TextView view;

    // view represents the view you want to watch. Should inherit from
    // TextView
    private GenericTextWatcher(View view) {

        if (view instanceof TextView)
            this.view = (TextView) view;
        else
            throw new ClassCastException(
                    "view must be an instance Of TextView");
    }

    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i,
            int before, int after) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int before,
            int count) {

        int id = view.getId();

        if (id == R.id.someview){
            //do the stuff you need to do for this particular view

            }



        if (id == R.id.someotherview){
            //do the stuff you need to do for this other particular view

            }

    }

    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {

    }
}
```

then to use it i do something like this to register it:

```
myEditText.addTextChangedListener(new ReusableTextWatcher(myEditText));
```