# EditText in ListView using ArrayAdapter

Tags: android, listview, android-arrayadapter

I've a ListView that displays a single button and a single EditText in each ListView row.

I'm using the ViewHolder pattern in my ArrayAdapter so all the buttons share a single OnClickListener. Picking up the button click is easy because onClick(View view) in my OnClickListener gives me the view (and I use getTag() to get my model object).

I can't figure out how to have a single TextWatcher to get the changed text, because there's no view parameter in TextWatcher onTextChanged() callback. Any help appreciated!

Comment: can you paste the code so that I can suggest where you need to change

Comment: for all the EditText  u want to create a single textWatcher

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The trick is to create a generic TextWatcher class. Then, each instance you create should be passed a reference of the View it will be placed into.

Example: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6172024/560600

Comment: Thanks - just what I was after. I ended up abandoning the EditText in ListView because of the world of pain focus problems http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2679948/focusable-edittext-inside-listview/2680077#2680077 (as Joe said "just not idiomatic-Android UI design"). For now a dialog box is good enough and I circle back on this later!

Comment: Yes! I should have remembered trying that as well. ListViews are really great for letting you display a list of memory-intensive resources, since they manage garbage collection for you. However, when I need to focus on the elements, I'm forced to use a ScrollView.

Answer (score 0):

For get the value of the EditText, in the Listener of the button i worked so:

```
viewHolder.button.setTag(viewHolder.YourEditText);
viewHolder.button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()){
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        int p = position;
        EditText edit = (EditText) v.getTag();
        String val = edit.getEditableText().toString();
       //do what you want with the value...
    }
}
```

Where `position` is `public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent){...`

If you'll need, i can post the entire AdapterClass.

Comment: I am having an issue with the way mine is setup. Can you provide some help... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20524417/listview-is-blank-while-using-getfilter-function