# Unable to use numberPassword as input type

Tags: android, textwatcher

I am trying to use the android:inputType="numberPassword" and it is not working. The numbers still appear in the EditText. This only happens when I add TextWatcher to switch to next EditText after entering in the first.

```
public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if (ps1.getText().hashCode() == s.hashCode()) {
            ps1.clearFocus();
            ps2.requestFocus();
            ps2.setCursorVisible(true);
        } else if (ps2.getText().hashCode() == s.hashCode()) {
            ps2.clearFocus();
            ps3.requestFocus();
            ps3.setCursorVisible(true);
        } else if (ps3.getText().hashCode() == s.hashCode()) {
            ps3.clearFocus();
            ps4.requestFocus();
            ps4.setCursorVisible(true);
        }
    }
```

What can I do to make this work properly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just write your **Edit-texts** in your **XML** like following.

```
<EditText
                android:id="@+id/ed_login_password"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:inputType="textPassword"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:text=""
/>
```

OR

Try out with programmatically **setinputtype** to the **Edittext**.

```
editPass.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT | InputType.TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_PASSWORD)
```

I think their is an problem in your Textwatcher so if you want to use **Single TextWatcher for multiple EditTexts**.

Look into the following link:-[How to use Single TextWatcher for multiple EditTexts?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5702771/how-to-use-single-textwatcher-for-multiple-edittexts/6172024#6172024)

OR

Access your Editexts in the following method of **TextWatcher**

```
public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {

 }
```

Hope it will helps you.

Comment: Thank you. Not that I think, using the same TextWatcher might be the problem as you said. I will check and tell how it goes.

Comment: These are the only possible solutions that we provided.I think their is nothing else.

Comment: I have provided the answer. Please look at it.

Comment: Can you please look into the link that i provided and it will same do as you do now.And I am telling you that their will be error in your Textwatcher.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/59343/discussion-between-born-to-win-and-vyprnoch).

Answer (score 1):

```
This problem can be solved without using deprecated android:password. Use the following code snippet, but do not reverse the sequence of calls:

    EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.MyEditText);
    editText.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER);
    editText.setTransformationMethod(PasswordTransformationMethod.getInstance());
```

Comment: try this:<EditText
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    style="@style/MyLargeTextBox"
    android:background="@android:drawable/editbox_background_normal"
    android:id="@+id/txtWebServicePIN"
    android:layout_row="3"
    android:layout_column="2"
    android:layout_columnSpan="2"
    android:minWidth="100dp"
    android:maxWidth="100dp"
    android:inputType="numberPassword"
    android:maxLength="6"/>

Comment: Could you tell me what is the change that may make this work?

Answer (score 1):

use below line in your xml file hope it will help you

```
android:password="true"
```

may be it is deprecated but it will solve your problem just try it

or you can try

```
android:inputType="textPassword|number"
```

ignore textPassword and only accept number but not password.

So you should use `android:inputType="textPassword|number"` with `android:password="true".`

that seems to be the only solution.

Comment: Not working. There are four edittexts. First and last get changed but the second and third remains as number.

Answer (score 0):

If anyone is looking for the answer its simple. Let your EditText have this line `android:inputType="numberPassword"`. No need to use the depreciated things. Just put the code in afterTextChanged instead of onTextChanged.

```
 @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if (ps1.getText().hashCode() == s.hashCode()) {
            ps1.clearFocus();
            ps2.requestFocus();
            ps2.setCursorVisible(true);
        } else if (ps2.getText().hashCode() == s.hashCode()) {
            ps2.clearFocus();
            ps3.requestFocus();
            ps3.setCursorVisible(true);
        } else if (ps3.getText().hashCode() == s.hashCode()) {
            ps3.clearFocus();
            ps4.requestFocus();
            ps4.setCursorVisible(true);
        }
    }
```

I am not sure why this works so anyone who knows may please explain.

Answer (score 0):

for me
    android:inputType="numberPassword" works for
    ValidationEditText