# Check if any edittext has changed in android

Tags: android

I have 10 edittexts in my layout. There is any way to check if any edittext values was changed? I know that I can use afterTextChange etc, but I want to know there is any one method to check all edittexts?

Comment: Did you try setting the same listener to all `EditText`s? That way you would get notified if any of them triggered an event.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Make each `EditText` have the same `TextChangedListener`

```
TextWatcher tw = new TextWatcher() {
    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

    }

    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

    }
};

editText1.addTextChangedListener(tw);
editText2.addTextChangedListener(tw);
...
```

Comment: The only problem I have with this is how to tell *which* `EditText` has been edited?

Comment: This is not important for me. I need only info if any Edittext has been edited

Comment: You could do something like this for that case @Squonk http://stackoverflow.com/a/6172024/2278598

Comment: I need  override onSelectionChanged(). Is there any similar way to that? I saw the source of TextWatcher.java. It only includes those 3 functions.