# How to use two or more text change listener in android

Tags: android

I'm creating conversion calculator like, example  http://173.199.129.149/~tiffinex/Dev/MTO/beta/index-calculator.php in android but used one text change listener. It works fine.When i tried with two or more text change listeners it does not give response and my app stops working, the code is given below,

```
et1 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText);
et2 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText2);
et3 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText3);   

et1.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
@Override
public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2)    {
}

@Override
public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

if (et1.getText().toString().equals("")) {
    et2.setText("0");
    et3.setText("0");
    } else {
        String s1 = et1.getText().toString();
        Double d1 = Double.parseDouble(s1);
        Double d3 = d1 * 12;
        String s3 = Double.toString(d3);

        et2.setText(s3);
        Double d4 = d1 * 0.3048;
        String s4 = Double.toString(d4);
        et3.setText(s4);
        }
}

@Override
public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {}
});

et2.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
@Override
public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int  i2) {
}

@Override
public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2)   {

if (et2.getText().toString().equals("")) {
    et1.setText("0");
    et3.setText("0");
} else {
    String s1 = et2.getText().toString();
    Double d1 = Double.parseDouble(s1);
    Double d3 = d1 / 12;
    String s3 = Double.toString(d3);

        et1.setText(s3);
        Double d4 = d1 * 39.40;
        String s4 = Double.toString(d4);
        et3.setText(s4);
    }

@Override
public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {
}
});

et3.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
@Override
public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2){
}

@Override
public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2)      {

if (et3.getText().toString().equals("")) {
et2.setText("0");
et1.setText("0");
} else {
    String s1 = et3.getText().toString();
    Double d1 = Double.parseDouble(s1);
    Double d3 = d1 * 39.40;
    String s3 = Double.toString(d3);

    et1.setText(s3);
    Double d4 = d1 / 3.48;
    String s4 = Double.toString(d4);
    et3.setText(s4);
    }

@Override
public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {}
});
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5702771/how-to-use-single-textwatcher-for-multiple-edittexts

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are getting this issue because you are also setting other 'EditText' in your `TextWatcher` which basically triggers a chain reaction of `setText()` calls. To overcome this, we can make sure that we trigger a `TextWatcher` callback only when the current focus of the user is on that `EditText` using `getCurrentFocus()`. In your code:

```
et1 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText); 
et2 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText2); 
et3 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText3);    

et1.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
@Override 
public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2)    {
} 

@Override 
public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

if (getCurrentFocus() == et1) {
    if (et1.getText().toString().equals("")) { 
        et2.setText("0"); 
        et3.setText("0"); 
        } else { 
            String s1 = et1.getText().toString();
            Double d1 = Double.parseDouble(s1);
            Double d3 = d1 * 12;
            String s3 = Double.toString(d3);

            et2.setText(s3);
            Double d4 = d1 * 0.3048;
            String s4 = Double.toString(d4);
            et3.setText(s4);
        } 
    }
} 

@Override 
public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {}
}); 

et2.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
@Override 
public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int  i2) {
} 

@Override 
public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2)   {

if (getCurrentFocus() == et2) {
    if (et2.getText().toString().equals("")) { 
        et1.setText("0"); 
        et3.setText("0"); 
    } else { 
        String s1 = et2.getText().toString();
        Double d1 = Double.parseDouble(s1);
        Double d3 = d1 / 12;
        String s3 = Double.toString(d3);

        et1.setText(s3);
        Double d4 = d1 * 39.40;
        String s4 = Double.toString(d4);
        et3.setText(s4);
    } 
}

@Override 
public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {
} 
}); 

et3.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
@Override 
public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2){
} 

@Override 
public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2)      {

if (getCurrentFocus() == et3) {
    if (et3.getText().toString().equals("")) { 
        et2.setText("0"); 
        et1.setText("0"); 
    } else { 
        String s1 = et3.getText().toString();
        Double d1 = Double.parseDouble(s1);
        Double d3 = d1 * 39.40;
        String s3 = Double.toString(d3);

        et1.setText(s3);
        Double d4 = d1 / 3.48;
        String s4 = Double.toString(d4);
        et3.setText(s4);
    } 
}

@Override 
public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {}
}); 
}
```